# Prove that this integral is diverge

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, continuity

Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a strictly decreasing continuous function, such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)=0$ prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}$ is diverge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that this integral is convergent. Let $N$ an integer. We have (as all the functions are positives):
$$\int_N^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}dx=\sum_{k\geq N}\int_k^{k+1}\frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}dx=\sum_{k\geq N}\int_0^1\frac{f(x+k)-f(x+k+1)}{f(x+k)}dx$$

Now for $k\geq N$ and $x\in [0,1]$, we have $f(x+N)\geq f(x+k)$. Hence $\displaystyle \frac{f(x+k)-f(x+k+1)}{f(x+k)}\geq\frac{f(x+k)-f(x+k+1)}{f(x+N)}$. Note that $\displaystyle \sum_{k\geq N}\frac{f(x+k)-f(x+k+1)}{f(x+N)}=1$ (we have used the fact that $f(u)\to 0$ as $u\to +\infty$) and hence
$$\sum_{k\geq N}\int_0^1\frac{f(x+k)-f(x+k+1)}{f(x+k)}dx\geq \sum_{k\geq N}\int_0^1\frac{f(x+k)-f(x+k+1)}{f(x+N)}dx=1$$
Hence
$$\int_N^{+\infty}\frac{f(x)-f(x+1)}{f(x)}dx\geq 1$$ for all $N$, and this is a contradiction.